# How Can I Create Textfield containing both a Input and a Select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I'm using Material UI with React Typescript in my website. And I want to create something like this which will be a reusable component, Cause it will be used in multiple different places. How Can I create something custom like this? Both the input and select field are inside same Box.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with *your attempt*? We can't just give you the code... it might not work in context with your code.

Comment: So I was initially trying to add a Select component to the Input field it self.  Which didn't work out. The other idea which I am having is create a textInput field along with a select component and wrap the both with a Box component. Which is yet to be tested. I wanted to have other opinion on it if there is any other good way for it. @kelsny

Comment: Wrapping them in a div, should be fine. Might be annoying if the textfield needs to interact with the Dropdown, but if it does not, wrapping them together is not a problem.